# skip non existing resourceDirectory - Maven

Tags: maven

When I execute the test in maven , skip non existing resourceDirectory and Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date is displayed.

Can you suggest steps to resolve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DHxM.png)
 Output

Comment: Add no links to image better copy the tests into the post instead...

Answer (score -3):

First of all, please note that the build is successful, so these are just warnings.

Maven cannot find the folders `D:\Seltestcases\maveninv\src\main\resources` and `D:\Seltestcases\maveninv\src\main\resources`. If the folders do not exist, they should be removed from wherever they are specified in the POM.

On the other hand, the code has been previously compiled, and no changes have been found, so it is not compiled again. Running `mvn clean` should allow the code to be compiled again.

Comment: What solution are you providing?